# Mana Ramp for White and Blue?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

What are some ramp cards for White or Blue decks (excluding High Tide in Blue)?

Formats: All excluding Vintage.

Comment: What format? Mana ramp isn't really white or blue's slice of the pie, so a lot of the answers are weirder older cards.

Comment: Tolarian Academy

Comment: Agreed that this could use more information. There are a large number of colorless mana artifacts and mana creatures. What are you looking to do?

Comment: @Jefromi: All except Vintage

Comment: Imprisoned in the Moon can be used against one of your own creatures to give you an extra land.

Answer (score 4):

White and Blue don't have much in the way of mana ramp. However, since you're looking at everything but Vintage, you do have some options:

White cards dealing with land tend towards restoring balance, and as such there are several card which can only get you land if an opponent has more already.

- [Knight of the White Orchid](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Knight%20of%20the%20White%20Orchid)
- [Kor Cartographer](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Kor%20Cartographer)
- [Oath of Lieges](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Oath%20of%20Lieges)
- [Planar Birth](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Planar%20Birth) (if you can dump lands into your graveyard)

Blue can, of course, *steal* land. It also has several card which cheat permanents into play, and happen to include land as an option.

- [Annex](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Annex) (in addition to many other cards which can steal any kind of permanent)
- [Arbiter of the Ideal](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Arbiter%20of%20the%20Ideal)
- [Braids, Conjurer Adept](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Braids%2C%20Conjurer%20Adept)
- [Dreamscape Artist](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Dreamscape%20Artist) (this is [Harrow](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Harrow), both color shifted and turned into a spellshaper at the same time; Planar Chaos be wacky)
- [Eternal Dominion](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Eternal%20Dominion) (of course, you don't need mana for casting spells afterwards, but you could still use mana for activating abilities)
- [Show and Tell](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Show%20and%20Tell)

In addition to adding more land to the battlefield, you can get more mileage out of your lands. "[Twiddle](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Twiddle)" effects are fairly common in blue, and Urza block had a slew of creatures and spells which would untap the same number of lands as their own mana cost, making the spell very nearly free, or if you had lands that tap for more than one mana, you could get more mana than you otherwise would have had.

- [Cloud of Faeries](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Cloud%20of%20Faeries)
- [Frantic Search](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Frantic%20Search)
- [Great Whale](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Great%20Whale)
- [Palinchron](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Palinchron)
- [Peregrine Drake](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Peregrine%20Drake)
- [Reset](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Reset)
- [Rewind](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Rewind)
- [Snap](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Snap)
- [Time Spiral](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Time%20Spiral)
- [Treachery](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Treachery)
- [Turnabout](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Turnabout)

You can also reduce your costs; you don't actually have more mana, but you can do more with the mana you have. (Affinity for Artifacts in particular is on many Blue cards.)

- [Arcane Melee](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Arcane%20Melee)
- [Ballyrush Banneret](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Ballyrush%20Banneret)
- [Council of the Absolute](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Council%20of%20the%20Absolute)
- [Daru Warchief](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Daru%20Warchief)
- [Etherium Sculptor](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Etherium%20Sculptor)
- [Grand Arbiter Agustin IV](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Grand%20Arbiter%20Agustin%20IV)
- [Herald of War](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Herald%20of%20War)
- [Hero of Iroas](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Hero%20of%20Iroas)
- [Mistform Warchief](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Mistform%20Warchief)
- [Stonybrook Banneret](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Stonybrook%20Banneret)
- [Stormscape Familiar](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Stormscape%20Familiar)
- [Sunscape Familiar](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Sunscape%20Familiar)
- [Warden of Evos Isle](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Warden%20of%20Evos%20Isle)

Finally, artifacts can do all of the above, from putting land onto the battlefield ([Burnished Hart](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Burnished%20Hart), [Explorers Scope](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Explorers%20Scope)), to tapping for mana ([Sol Ring](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Sol%20Ring), [Darksteel Ingot](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Darksteel%20Ingot)), to making your lands tap for more mana ([Gauntlet of Power](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Gauntlet%20of%20Power), [Caged Sun](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Caged%20Sun)), to reducing costs ([Cloud Key](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Cloud%20Key), [Helm of Awakening](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Helm%20of%20Awakening)), and even Twiddle effects ([Candelabra of Tawnos](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Candelabra%20of%20Tawnos), [Sword of Feast and Famine](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Sword%20of%20Feast%20and%20Famine)).

It ought to be obvious, but this answer is by no means an exhaustive listing of your options. You're not going to vomit a deck full of lands onto the table playing a White/Blue deck, but there are still ways for you to get ahead in the game.

Comment: No one has yet mentioned Tithe or Weathered Wayfarer.

Comment: @HaoYe, While excellent cards, neither are mana ramp.

Comment: 'You're not going to vomit a deck full of lands onto the table...' That is such a fantastic way of putting it. I always felt like my green ramp decks were somehow 'vomiting' or 'expelling' their mana because of all the shuffle and draw.

Answer (score 0):

- [Azorius Signet](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Azorius%20Signet)
- [Land Tax](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Land%20Tax)
- [Saprazzan Skerry](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Saprazzan%20Skerry) and [Remote Farm](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Remote%20Farm) (I don't see people using this, but maybe?)

Comment: Land Tax is not mana ramp. It can help make sure you don't _miss_ your land drops, but it doesn't accelerate your mana in any way.

Comment: yes Brian, not exactly, I thought I should remind of this one, maybe it's useful in other forms (if you are use using moxes and petals). White has nothing good like Dark Rituals, so it's good exploring other possibilites...